# I can no longer SSH to a VM on GCP after breaking ssh configuration

Tags: ssh, redhat, google-compute-engine, gcloud, owner

I am starting to use GCP.
I fixed a server (redhat), connected to it (using SSH, directly from GCP console) and deployed my application, everything worked well
To try to fix something I played with the authorizations on some folder of my server. And stupidly changed the owner of VAR folder.
result -> I can not anymore connect to my server! Meaning, I cannot reverse this change and fix it.

When I try (gcloud command, or directly from console) here is what I get from the log (which totally comfort me on my analysis of the bug) :

> Oct 18 08:54:41 serverlinux systemd: Started Google Compute Engine
>   Instance Setup. Oct 18 08:54:41 serverlinux systemd: Starting OpenSSH
>   server daemon... Oct 18 08:54:41 serverlinux sshd: /var/empty/sshd
>   must be owned by root and not group or world-writable. Oct 18 08:54:41
>   serverlinux systemd: sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited,
>   status=255/n/a Oct 18 08:54:41 serverlinux systemd: Failed to start
>   OpenSSH server daemon. Oct 18 08:54:41 serverlinux systemd: Unit
>   sshd.service entered failed state. Oct 18 08:54:41 serverlinux
>   systemd: sshd.service failed.

Question: Do I have another way to connect to my server, and then fix this bug? Or I need to delete everything, redo everything (and be more careful next time I am playing with authorizations :( )

Comment: Did you try rebooting you VM to see if it resolve the issue? I changed the permission of `\var` directory and I was able to reproduce the issue. However, after a reboot the default permission of the directory is automatically recovered.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable interactive access to the serial console of your VM and then troubleshoot the instance. For more information visit [Interacting with the Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) article.